# In PowerBI Embedded, "Copy" command does not appear when configured via customize menu commands

Tags: copy, command, config, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to [customize menu commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/change-visual-commands#customize-menu-commands) in a PowerBI Embedded application. My code is almost literally copy-pasted from the example and passes Typescript type-check:

```
// The new settings that you want to apply to the report.
const newSettings = {
    commands: [
        {
            copy: {
                displayOption: models.CommandDisplayOption.Hidden,
            }
        }
    ]
};

// Update the settings by passing in the new settings you have configured.
await report.updateSettings(newSettings);
```

The article claims, that command is only available in `Edit` mode, but when I switch report into edit mode, i still don't see the copy command.

Update: it looks like command configuration does not work at-all, commands like 'spotlight' are not switched-off by it, neither when it is passed in initial config, nor in later configuration update.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see the copy command in embedded report but for spotlight and other commands the code is working fine as given in your reference link, Please find the below code snippet to enable/disable them:

```js
const newSettings = {
    commands: [
        {
            spotlight: {
                displayOption: models.CommandDisplayOption.Enabled,
            }
        }
    ]
};

await report.updateSettings(newSettings);
```

You can try this on Power BI Playground:
https://playground.powerbi.com/dev-sandbox